# How make LiveCD install, from Linux From Scratch(LFS)?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, linux-from-scratch

I Build linux, LFS, and I want to build LFS to ISO and can run as live CD and can install LFS GUI to hardisk. can everybody help me?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to make a liveCD that will boot and run then a guide like this may help http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/OLD/bootcd-2.6-udev-nptl.txt , but to make a system that will install on any generic PC (like your own distrobution essentially) you would need to either package several kernels, or one generic one, this is assuming that the PCs are alll using the same architecture and hardware (32 or 64 bit, then intel VS amd, then realtek etc for ethernet driver or wifi driver.) it's a lengthy process compared to a livecd that will just boot

Comment: The link that you've suggested is way too old. It was written more than 10 years ago.

Comment: Many thanks for your effort. I succeed build livecd with add option kernel zram, autofs, I copied slax config and this worked